# how do i replace character from string in list?

Tags: string, list, replace, python-3.11

I wanted to try to make a simple game to play in my terminal and I am stuck on this problem.

I have tried

```py
l[y][x] = l[y][x].replace(' ','2')
```

And

```py
l[y][x] = '2'
```

And all of these returns a type error
`'str' object does not support item assignment`.
how do I solve the problem above?

Edit:
`l` contains

```py
['111111111',
 '120000001',
 '100000001',
 '100000001',
 '111111111'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your list l into characters - what you have is a list of string elements.

```
#convert elements into characters 
m = [list(x) for x in l]
print(m)

print(m[1][2])

m[1][2] = m[1][2].replace('0', '9')
print(m[1][2])
```